Can I harvest Token2022 fees in an Anchor program?
To collect fees, the withdraw authority of a Token2022 using the transfer fee extension has to withdraw manually from each Token Accounts: https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/transfer-fee
This can be done from a client.
I wish for the withdraw authority to be a PDA of my Solana program. I won't be able to use a client since there is no keypair. I need to have a function in my program that collects those fees.
Is it possible in Anchor ? I can't find any ressources about it.
Thank you.
EDIT: I found withdraw_withheld_tokens_from_accounts function spl_token_2022 crate: https://docs.rs/spl-token-2022/latest/spl_token_2022/extension/transfer_fee/instruction/fn.withdraw_withheld_tokens_from_accounts.html
Can't find any example of its use. Does it only withdraw the tokens from 1 account (so I would need to use it to every single account that has withheld tokens, so pretty much un-usable), or does it withdraw from all accounts ?

There's more documentation at the actual enum description at https://docs.rs/spl-token-2022/latest/spl_token_2022/extension/transfer_fee/instruction/enum.TransferFeeInstruction.html#variant.WithdrawWithheldTokensFromAccounts and here's a test using it: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/92469a79ed655b52921d2f39a62ad64d727c2075/token/program-2022-test/tests/transfer_fee.rs#L1521

Based on the PR it appears you can use it to withdraw from several source accounts, only limitation will be normal transaction limitations (CU, txn size): https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/3128
